# Eclipse Xtend 2.15.0 uses dark theme for .xtend source files

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, xtend

My eclipse version `Photon Release (4.8.0)` with `Eclipse Xtend 2.15.0` plugin always displays `.xtend` source files in dark theme mode, I even tried to change the global theme in Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance but it changed nothing.
Did some of you encountered a similiar problem and know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to download the Eclipse_Color_Themes plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace, It gives you more options that in my experience are easier to work with and less buggy.  Go to help, eclipse marketplace, search for the plugin.  After installing, go to Window, preferences, appearance, general, color themes.

Answer (score 0):

Something was wrong with my workplace, I created a new one and now everything looks and works fine.